# How to fix broken assets connection on an Angular site embedded to WordPress?

Tags: angular, wordpress

I'm embedding an Angular application on a WordPress website into the admin menu page of my plugin. In general it works. But I think because I have to change the base href to `<base href="/wp-admin/admin.php">`, the application cannot find the assets after integrating the app to the WordPress dashboard.

The requested path of my assets is for example:

`https://bwc:8890/assets/icons/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2`
or 
`https://bwc:8890/wp-admin/assets/monaco/vs/loader.js`

So I have many asset files which are not found and the UI is broken:

[image]

The most difficult part is the `https://bwc:8890/wp-admin/assets/monaco/vs/loader.js`. Because this is a third party package, I have no idea how to manually adjust the path of the file.

By the way: I've followed this instructions for embedding the application: [Trying to embed angular app in wordpress dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105912/trying-to-embed-angular-app-in-wordpress-dashboard-is-it-possible-to-create-a-c)

I've already tried to play with the deploy path, but Angular never builds the correct connection to the asset files.

Do you have an idea how to fix this?